# Remove array elements and populate them in another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to separate each month's dates in each iteration. I have an array `var selected=["pre populated with special dates"]` which have all the selected dates. Now in this code how can I modify it to remove the dates for each month from `selected[]` array and populate `thisMonthDates[]` with only this particular month's dates in each iteration?

```
   var ind=start.getMonth();
            var thisMonthDates = [];
            while(ind<=yearDifference){    
                for (var k = 0; k < selectedArrayLength; k++) {
                    if (new Date(selected[k]).getMonth() == monthIndex[ind]) {
                        thisMonthDates = selected[k];
                        //console.log(new Date(thisMonthDates[k]));
                    }
                }
                for(var eachDt=0; eachDt<thisMonthDates.length; eachDt++) {
                   //code for highlighting the dates
                }
                ind++;
            }
```

Following is the `selected[]` array contents. And `thisMonthDates[]` is an empty array before the loop.

```
selected = [Date 2015-01-06T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-01-13T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-01-20T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-01-27T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-02-03T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-02-10T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-02-17T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-02-24T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-03-03T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-03-10T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-03-17T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-03-24T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-03-31T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-04-07T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-04-14T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-04-21T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-04-28T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-05-05T19:00:00.000Z,Date 2015-05-12T19:00:00.000Z, 
Date 2015-05-19T19:00:00.000Z];
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: What does `selected` and `thisMonthDates` look like before the loop?

Comment: @PeterAshwell I edited the question with the selected[] array.

Comment: @aduch I edited the question with the selected[] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop should do the trick

```
for (var k = 0; k < selectedArrayLength; k++) {
    if (new Date(selected[k]).getMonth() == monthIndex[ind]) {
        thisMonthDates.push(selected.splice(k, 1));
        k--; // since we removed an element we need to decrement k
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this example helps:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XbnJV0B0bO00o4iJdBtV

```
var selected = [];
var JANUARY = 0
var FEBRUARY = 1
var MARCH = 2;
selected.push(new Date(2015, FEBRUARY, 15));
selected.push(new Date(2015, JANUARY, 10));
selected.push(new Date(2015, FEBRUARY, 6));
selected.push(new Date(2015, MARCH, 25));

var thisMonth = [];

for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    if (selected[i].getMonth() === FEBRUARY) {
        thisMonth.push(selected[i]);
    }
}

console.log(selected);
console.log(thisMonth);
```

And the output:

```
[Sun Feb 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT), Sat Jan 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT), Fri Feb 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT), Wed Mar 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)]
[Sun Feb 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT), Fri Feb 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)]
```

Comment: And the next time when my loop iterates it again have to iterate through all those dates which creates issue. selected[] array should have to have less elements in it. As you can see there is another loop at the end which will be used to highlight the dates later on.